# Select sum and count of every transaction per day and display it

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am making a monitoring system. My target is to show the sum and count of my transactions per day. I have provided a screenshot of my target. Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

**View**

```
<tr>
  <th scope="col"><i class="far fa-calendar-alt mr-2"></i>Date</th>
  <th scope="col"><i class="fas fa-user-tie mr-2"></i>Total Transaction</th> 
  <th scope="col"><i class="fas fa-user-tie mr-2"></i>Amount</th> 
   <th scope="col"><i class="fas fa-user-tie mr-2"></i>Action</th> 
      </tr>
```

**Controller**

```
public function testing()
    {
        
        
        $list = $this->repo->function_etc();
        $data = array();
        $no = $_POST['start'];
        foreach ($list as $person) {
            $no++;
            $row = array();
            $row[] = $person->dateUp;
            $row[] = number_format($person->amount);
            $row[] = number_format($person->count);
            $row[] ='<a class="btn btn-sm buttoon" href="https://sample.com/etcetc='.$person->dateUp.'" ><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i>View</a>';
             $data[] = $row;
        }
        
        $output = array(
           "data" => $data,
        );
        
        echo json_encode($output);
    }
```

**Model**:

```
//maybe i'm missing something here?

      private function function_etc()
            {
                
                $this->db->select('*');
                $this->db->from($this->tableDashboard);
                $this->db->where('transReference !=', '');
                $this->db->where('trans_siteName','https://somewhere.com/');
                $this->db->select_sum('tbl_transaction.amount');
                
                $this->db->group_by('tbl_transaction.dateUp');
            $query = $this->db->get();
                return $query->result();
               
            }
```

Comment: The `*` in your select will not automagically `COUNT()` and `SUM()` the appropriate columns. You will need to address that 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your select section of The query should handle the count and sum.

```php
private function function_etc()
{
    $this->db->select('*, sum(amount) amt, count(ID) num');
    $this->db->from($this->tableDashboard);
    $this->db->where('transReference !=', '');
    $this->db->where('trans_siteName','https://somewhere.com/');
    $this->db->select_sum('tbl_transaction.amount');
    
    $this->db->group_by('tbl_transaction.date');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

Comment: Exactly what i'm looking for. Thank you so much. Tested it out and it works perfect. Thank you and to everyone who answered my question. Appreciate you all

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT Date, COUNT(ID) AS  'TranCount', SUM(amount) 
FROM table
WHERE DATE(date )= DATE(now()) 
GROUP BY date
```

Answer (score 1):

MODEL FUNCTION

```php
function tested() {   
    $this->db->select('Date,sum(Amount) as Total');
    $this->db->from('tbl_transaction');
    //$this->db->where('transReference !=', '');
    //$this->db->where('trans_siteName','https://somewhere.com/');
    
    $this->db->group_by('Date');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

CONTROLLER FUNCTION: To process the database response

```php
function tested() {
    $this->load->model('repo');

    $result = $this->repo->tested();
 
    foreach ($result as $k => $v) {
        $Date =  $v['Date'];
        $Total = $v['Total'];

        echo    $Date.  $Total .  "<br>";
    }
}
```